# Acquisition attempt failed during the initializing c3p0 pool

Tags: spring, hibernate, postgresql, c3p0

I am new to J2EE technologies and trying to create a basic web application with JSF, Spring and Hibernate. I also use PostgreSQL. During the server startup, I encounter this exception:

```
WARNING: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@173b4cf -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.getProtocol(Unknown Source)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.knownURL(Unknown Source)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.acceptsURL(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(Unknown Source)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.driver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:240)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:131)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:156)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:145)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:200)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1086)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1073)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:648)

Dec 09, 2015 11:13:21 AM com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask run
WARNING: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@173b4cf -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.getProtocol(Unknown Source)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.knownURL(Unknown Source)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.acceptsURL(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(Unknown Source)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.driver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:240)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:131)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:156)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:145)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:200)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1086)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1073)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:648)

Dec 09, 2015 11:13:21 AM com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask run
WARNING: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask@5e53d -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.getProtocol(Unknown Source)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.knownURL(Unknown Source)
at sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver.acceptsURL(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(Unknown Source)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.driver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:240)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:131)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:156)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:145)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:200)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1086)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquireAndDecrementPendingAcquiresWithinLockOnSuccess(BasicResourcePool.java:1073)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:44)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$ScatteredAcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:648)
```

I gave my configuration files and related class below:

application-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/SomeDB" />
    <property name="username" value="postgres" />
    <property name="password" value="1234" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="tr.mypackage" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="tr.mypackage" />

</beans>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
<display-name>Some Display Name</display-name>

<!-- JSF -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- SPRING -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/application-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- OTHER -->
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Person.java

```
package tr.mypackage;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import com.sun.istack.internal.NotNull;

@Entity
@Table(name="person_t")
public class Person {
    @Id
    @NotNull
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;

    @Column
    private String firstName;

    public Person(){

    }

    public Person(int id, String firstName) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

}
```

So, is there any idea about where my error is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The immediate cause of your problem is that you haven't actually provided any Connection information to the c3p0 DataSource you have hibernate build with these settings.

```
<prop key="hibernate.connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</prop>
```

See the [Spring docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate5/LocalSessionFactoryBean.html#setDataSource-javax.sql.DataSource-): The DataSource you have configured in Spring is distinct from the one hibernate's SessionFactory might build internally. You've provided enough configuration to cause hibernate to build a DataSource, but you haven't provided the `hibernate.connection.*` parameters necessary to properly configure it.

The easiest thing to do would be to get rid of the DataSource you've configured in Spring and finish configuring your c3p0 DataSource in hibernate. See [hibernate docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/manual/en-US/html_single/#configuration-hibernatejdbc) for the various Connection parameters you should supply that currently are missing. You can also set [c3p0 configuration parameters](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuration_properties) as `hibernate.c3p0.fooBarBlah` (where `fooBarBlah` should obviously be replaced by real parameter names). [Note that for parameters like `max_size` and `maxPoolSize` with both a hibernate name and a c3p0 name, the [hibernate name will override c3p0-name settings](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#hibernate-specific).]

Alternatively, you can get rid of the two hibernate properties above, and supply your own DataSource configured in Spring. If you want Connection pooling, you probably don't your DataSource to be a `org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource`. You can configure a `com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource` directly in Spring, the same way you've configured the unpooled DriverManagerDataSource. See the section "Have Spring Manage the Pool" in [this article](http://syntx.io/configuring-c3p0-connection-pooling-with-spring-and-hibernate/) for an example.

Comment: thank you very much. i removed c3p0 related things, now it is running without any problem.

Comment: yes, i removed above 2 properties and now it's running without any error.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse and you are facing this error, then you just need to change your mysql connector (which worked totally fine in my case).

The newer versions are using `caching_sha2_password`.